# Query list index with django

Tags: sql, django

i have a problem with django when i use these two arrays:
institution_ids [(2,), (16,)]
project_ids [(3,), (1,)]

in this query:

`queryset = Patient.active.filter(tss_id__in=institution_ids, project_id__in = project_ids)`

it gives me back all the combinations, but I need this kind of result:

```
queryset = Patient.active.filter(tss_id=institution_ids[0], project_id = project_ids[0])
queryset += Patient.active.filter(tss_id=institution_ids[1], project_id = project_ids[1])
```

how can i do?
Thanks
Giuseppe

Comment: Python's terminology for an array is list. Your lists contain tuples and not integers, you first need to convert your list of tuples to a list of integers. `institution_ids = [my_tuple[0] for my_tuple in institution_ids]` this will give you `institution_ids = [2, 16]`

Answer (score 0):

What you search for is an OR statement.
You can do it using Q object.

> In Django, we cannot directly use the OR operator to filter the
> QuerySet. For this implementation, we have to use the Q() object. By
> using the Q() object in the filter method, we will be able to use the
> OR operator between the Q() objects.

For example-

If you want to get all objects with tss_id in institution array and all objects with project__id__in projects_id array you will use it like this.

```
queryset = Patient.active.filter(Q(tss_id__in=institution_ids) | project_id__in = project_ids))
```

Pay attention- you need to import Q.

Another option -

Using union

> New in Django 1.11. Uses SQL’s UNION operator to combine the results of two or more QuerySets.
> The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the all=True argument.

For example :

```
queryset = Patient.active.filter(tss_id=institution_ids[0], project_id = project_ids[0])
queryset2 = Patient.active.filter(tss_id=institution_ids[1], project_id = project_ids[1])
Combined_queryset = queryset.union(queryset2)
```

Comment: this  cannot be an answer this can be comment

Comment: and if want to use for? an example?

Comment: I’ve edited my comment.

Comment: It gives me everything back and it shouldn't happen if I wanted to use a for where I take the elements and concatenate the queryset?

Comment: I’ve added another option. Using union.

Comment: thank, but generates "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Comment: I don’t think it’s related. 
Maybe you don’t have element in the index you specified.

Comment: Tuple should contain 2 elements…